# How can I remove or drop multi indexes in a list from a dataframe in python without compromising the dataset?

Tags: python

I have tried using the .drop() func to remove the particular indexes from the dataframe but the remaining dataframe after the removal seems to have lost data in some columns. I'm puzzled as to why columns which used to have data displaying NaN.

Comment: You must provide a fully reproducible example, there is no way to help you otherwise.

Comment: can u pls post what is the target `df`` as a table &  `some columns` has lot amibiguity..So pls provide your code & minimum reproducible example

Comment: keep in mind, you can `drop` full row or full column only... 
if you want to change/delete specific value in the cell, check `replace`, or `.loc` or `where` or god knows which  options as you have not provided any example

Comment: Could you share some of your code, and what you've tried already? Also, is this a pandas dataframe?